# how to retrieve the structure of an OLAP cube

Tags: mdx, olap

I have access to an OLAP catalog, but I am not familiar with MDX. I am looking for the MDX equivalent of SQL:

```
SHOW DATABASES; 
SHOW TABLES;
```

I was looking at [MDX language reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms145595), but I could not find a way of getting the schema, the cube metadata. Thanks for helping.

Comment: Which OLAP solution are you using on top of you MySQL DB : icCube, MSAS, Mondrian ?

Comment: I am not the OLAP provider, I am just a consumer. The mysql queries were only examples of the metadata queries that I wanted to do in order to get the OLAP structure (which I do not know).

Answer (score 4):

You can use the $SYSTEM database to query your objects.

Use `SELECT * FROM $SYSTEM.DISCOVER_SCHEMA_ROWSETS` to get a list of things you can query. In your case it would most likely be `DBSCHEMA_CATALOG`, `DBSCHEMA_TABLES` and `MDSCHEMA_CUBES`.

This is very rough information, and using stuff like Preet suggests might be favorable in the end.

Comment: I am doing all this from PHP so I cannot install extra stuff, but I think you gave me a good direction. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

There is answer [List dimension members with MDX query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6266850/list-dimension-members-with-mdx-query) to show how list dimensions.

This [open source project (TSSASM)](http://tssasm.codeplex.com/) shows how to query access the cube structure from a TSQL database.

However I think you may need XMLA commands to see what you need.